# creating a simple chrome autofill function

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to make my first ever autofill chrome extension and I'm struggling to actually fill the form. I would be filling out a field on ONE specific website only. There are only 2 possible values I want to fill in this field at random, and then I want to hit the "submit" button (but I believe once I have the general code, I can figure this last step out).

Here is my manifest.json:

```
   {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Call Hacks",
  "description": "This extension hacks calls",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background" : {
  "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Start hacking!"
    },

  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

Here is my background.js:

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'script.js'
    });
});
```

Here is my script.js:

```
(function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"document.getElementById('example').value = 'name'"});
})();
```

I am able to run without errors, but upon clicking my icon, nothing happens. I am expecting "name" to pop up in the field. I am testing my code on a tester webpage and I believe the field is called "example". Any help would be much appreciated.